# Ajax/Jquery request is not sending cookies

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I use [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) script for cross domain (subdomain) uploads. The main page is www.example.com and I upload files to st2.example.com.

Everything works fine but the problem is that I need to send cookies with each ajax request and for some reason it's not possible. The documentation of this script says:

> If you need to send along cookies (e.g. for authentication), set the
>   withCredentials $.ajax() setting as fileupload widget option:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
}
});
```

This does not work for me. I tried to add the line

```
withCredentials: true
```

in three different places:

- to $('#fileupload').fileupload({
- to $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
- to $.ajax({

First 2 does not work at all. The third works only for **HEAD** requests. **HEAD** requests send cookies but **OPTIONS** and **POST** not. I checked this in browser console in Firefox and Chrome.

My question is: where is the problem that OPTIONS and POST requests does not send any cookies?

Below is my script. This example contains "withCredentials: true" in all 3 places where I have tested it.

```
    <script>
    var defaultthumbnail = '<img class="thum5" src="/upload.png">';
    $(function () {
    var formData = $('#fileupload').serializeArray();
    'use strict';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url:'//st2.example.com/',
    });

    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/i,
    autoUpload:true,
    maxNumberOfFiles:20,
    maxFileSize:4000000,

  xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},

    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
    .test(window.navigator.userAgent)
    });

    if ($.support.cors) {
    $.ajax({
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    type: 'HEAD'
    }).fail(function () {
    $('<div class="error"/>')
    .text('Server is not available')
    .appendTo('#fileupload');
    });
    } 
    });
    </script>
```

File on st2.example.com contains:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Cloudflare. First of all the browser sends OPTIONS request to the server to see if can upload files. OPTIONS requests always come without cookies, that's why Cloudflare issues another captcha challenge page instead of forwarding the request to the server.